# How do gitlab merge branches keep their.gitlab-ci.yml files from being merged?

Tags: git, gitlab, cicd

The contents of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file for dev and build branches are different due to requirements, and I expect that the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file will not be merged when dev is merged into build.

Can the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file be configured to do this?

If so, how to configure it?

Comment: Why not just have the same file and choose jobs depending on branch?

Answer (score 1):

As KamilCuk commented this is not really the the idea of Gitlab CI and there is no way to make changes to the file in a branch and then not have those changes merged to the main branch.

Most often feature branches will not need different configuration *from eachother* so it's actually quite nice to have a single file to specify this across branches. (Otherwise you'd have to do some boilerplate changes everytime you start a new branch).

Often you'd have something like this:

```yaml
.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - make

build_main:
  extends: .build
  before_script:
    - ./ci/export_version_number.sh
  only:
    - $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH

build_feature:
  extends: .build
  variables: 
    ON_FEATURE_BRANCH: true
  only:
    - /^feature\/.*$/
```

Using this setup you can inherit common settings using the [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) keyword. (The `.` in front of a job name makes it [hidden](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/index.html#hide-jobs)). This is much more powerful than changing the CI file in a branch because you can use this  to customize jobs without needing to change a branch first.

### Workaround

If you really wanted to I suppose you could do something like this:
.gitlab-ci.yml:

```yaml
include: include/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.yml
```

And then you can place `.yml` files named after your branches in `include/refs/heads` (prior to Gitlab 14.5) or `include/` (after Gitlab 14.5).

This way changes are still be merged to your main branch but they would not be used once there. However, in general I'd still recommend embracing the fact that the file is the same and just making the distinction in with the `only`, `except` and `workflow` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

```
command line:git config --global merge.ours.driver true

project .gitattributes file: paste the command: .gitlab-ci.yml merge=ours
```